# How to get the unique set of count for rows with different values for a certain hour

Tags: mysql

select id, hour, count from stats;

```
1, 0, 2
2, 0, 20
3, 1, 10
4, 1, 20 
5, 2, 10
5, 2, 30
```

I would want the output (hour, count) to render as

```
0, 22
1, 30
2, 40
```

How do I perform a unique count for the hour interval?

Comment: what do you mean by "unique count"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select hour, sum(count)
from stats
group by hour
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the group by clause:

```
SELECT  hour, count(id)
GROUP BY hour;
```

So for this dataset:

```
1, 0, 2
2, 0, 20
3, 1, 10
4, 1, 20 
5, 2, 10
5, 2, 30
```

you will get

```
0, 2
1, 2
2, 2
```

If you want to get the sum for that hour use `SUM()`

```
SELECT  hour, sum(`count`)
GROUP BY hour;
```

**NOTE:** Try not to use the word count as a field name because it is also a key word in mysql

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`SUM()`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php) function to achieve that:

```
SELECT hour, sum(`count`) AS `TotalCOUNT`
FROM stats
GROUP BY hour
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03cad/4)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go for
 SELECT hour,sum(count) FROM stats
GROUP by hour;

Here is the reference for group by clause
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php